# Django App Improperly Configured - The app module has multiple filesystem locations

Tags: django, uwsgi

I think I've really screwed something up. On my django app (the production one) I pushed a major update and am get an "Internal Server Error" whenever I try to go to my domain. I am getting an error in my uwsgi logs:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.8 (64bit) on [Thu Jan 29 00:36:43 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 11 December 2014 17:29:38
os: Linux-3.13.0-41-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 25 14:40:34 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-172-31-9-208
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
chdir() to /home/ubuntu/web/app
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 15922
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /home/ubuntu/web/ppuwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:08:40)  [GCC 4.8.2]
Set PythonHome to /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xb57780
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72768 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /home/ubuntu/web/ to pythonpath.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 104, in create
    entry = module.default_app_config
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default_app_config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pennypledge/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup 
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
 File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 107, in create
    return cls(entry, module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.path = self._path_from_module(app_module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 70, in _path_from_module
    "with a 'path' class attribute." % (module, paths))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app module <module 'ledger' (namespace)> has multiple filesystem locations (['./ledger', '/home/ubuntu/web/app/ledger']); you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 8549, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8549|app: -1|req: -1/1] 71.195.197.2 () {42 vars in 828 bytes} [Wed Jan 28 17:36:54 2015] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8549|app: -1|req: -1/2] 71.195.197.2 () {42 vars in 814 bytes} [Wed Jan 28 17:36:56 2015] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8549|app: -1|req: -1/3] 71.195.197.2 () {38 vars in 640 bytes} [Wed Jan 28 17:37:09 2015] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8549|app: -1|req: -1/4] 162.243.163.123 () {40 vars in 751 bytes} [Wed Jan 28 17:37:09 2015] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8549|app: -1|req: -1/5] 71.195.197.2 () {40 vars in 748 bytes} [Wed Jan 28 17:37:10 2015] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 8549|app: -1|req: -1/6] 71.195.197.2 () {38 vars in 591 bytes} [Wed Jan 28 17:37:11 2015] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

I have no idea what is going on: `The app module <module 'ledger' (namespace)> has multiple filesystem locations (['./ledger', '/home/ubuntu/web/app/ledger']); you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute.`.

Here is my settings.py file:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<SECRET_KEY>'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com','.example2.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ledger',
    'extension',
    'plugin',
    'emailmanager',
    'bookmarklet',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pennypledge.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pennypledge.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'ledger.User'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'database',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'MST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False #I don't think we care about TZ's. If we do then we need to change the deleting of transaction code.


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'C:/pennypledge/pennypledge/static/',
    '/Users/croberts/pennypledge/static/',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
    'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'ledger.custom_social_auth.YoutubeOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Lastly, when I try to checkout a previous version of the code. I get the same problems.

**edit - adding uwsgi.conf file**

```
# file: /etc/init/ppuwsgi.conf 
description "uWSGI server for PennyPledge"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --home /home/ubuntu/web/app/ --socket /home/ubuntu/web/ppuwsgi.sock --chmod-socket=666 --module=pennypledge.wsgi --pythonpath /home/ubuntu/web/ -H /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/pennypledge --logto /home/ubuntu/web/logs/uwsgi.log --chdir=/home/ubuntu/web/app --chmod-socket=666
```

I don't know why the problem would be uwsgi's fault as I only updated the Django project.

Comment: Can we see your uWSGI configuration? A `.ini` file or something? And your `wsgi.py`

Comment: My problem was Visual Studio:  I renamed an app, then moved it, and VS didn't move all of the folders.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The problem was that I deleted an `__init__.py` file. Apparently, django uses them to know which folders are *apps*, so they are kind of important.

Comment: I had similar error and this gave me clue to my solution, __init__.py defined default_app_config = 'app_name.apps.Class_name' and apps.py also defined 
class Class_name(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'                I have comment default_app_config in __init__.py

Comment: But one need a 'path' class attribute: ..you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute.

Comment: I thought __init__.py was not necessary in Python 3

Comment: not for namespaces. Django here thinks that this is a namespace and doesn't know where to find the app.

Comment: What caught me out was I added __init__.py, but hadn't run locally. When I ran docker build, my __pycache__ directories were being sent to the daemon, which seemed to cause the error even with __init__.py created. I had to add __pycache__ to the .dockerignore before everything worked as expected.

Comment: __init__.py file needs to go under the app directory; under ledger in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your `ledger` app. Is this a custom app?

From the Django source code, the error comes from `_path_from_module(app_module)`

```
    # Filesystem path to the application directory eg.
    # u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin'. Unicode on
    # Python 2 and a str on Python 3.
    if not hasattr(self, 'path'):
        self.path = self._path_from_module(app_module)
```

As a quick fix, if this is your app, you can configure it with an `AppConfig` subclass that has a valid `path` attribute, which will stop the bug from executing. I'm looking into it further now.

If `ledger` is not your app, and you've updated it through `pip` or some other means, this explains why checking out an older version does not fix the problem. Try getting an older version of that app from its repository (if applicable) and submit a bug report.

Comment: This is a custom app. Can you post an example of how to subclass AppConfig. I'm looking at the docs but still a little confused.

Comment: Haha! I got it! I had deleted the \_\_init__.py file. I don't know what that does or why it would work locally on my machine, but that fixed it.

Comment: Interesting. Init files can be used for lots of stuff, like loading and configuring modules, the admin site, etc. Just make sure you see what it was doing inside to cause the error. If it supports your auth user model, you don't want to mess it up!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the application directory, edit the file `apps.py` and add the `path` attribute as the error says. For example:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
import os
from django.conf import settings


class TranslatorConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'translator'
    path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'translator')
```

And ... BOOM!!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run the python script in virtual environment from outside, so I used an activation script which I was importing before the start of main script. That activation script contained sys.path.append(".") which was causing an additional entry of application path. Removing this fixed the issue.

Probably you are also inserting duplicate path somewhere.