# Deploying Django app to Azure throws Error occurred while reading WSGI handler

Tags: python, django, azure

I'm trying to deploy a Django App to Azure App Services through Visual Studio 2015 and stuck with an error on server. This question already have been posted but no valid work around has given.

I'm using:

- Python 3.4
- Django 1.11.3

*On localhost everything is working perfectly*

**The error displayed on browser.**

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

**I have enabled logging for wsgi from 'App Settings' and got detailed error:**

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 
111, in create
entry = module.default_app_config
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default_app_config'
```

Here is the log file with all traceback : [log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B86zZGKbM0ZcaC1UTFpFY1NMZTg)

This is my uwsgi.py file :

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xSettings.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Web.config** and **ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py** are the same as pointed in documentation [Configuring Python with Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure)

Initial I was thinking it's a problem with my python version and have created a dummy Django app, created the environment from the same python version, installed all packages from requirements.txt from my real project and published it, and everything worked perfectly (see the dummy [app](http://djangowebproject.azurewebsites.net/))

Any idea, thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205264/django-app-improperly-configured-the-app-module-has-multiple-filesystem-locati. Have you check this on?

Comment: I know about that question and have checked it ... but you have made me check one more time, and obviously in one of the app were missing a __init__ file.