# Django Deployment Failure in Pythonanywhere

Tags: django, web-deployment, pythonanywhere

Getting this error in my error logs when deploying my site

```html
2021-04-23 16:20:38,663: Error running WSGI application
2021-04-23 16:20:38,676: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app module <module 'tracker' (namespace)> has multiple filesystem locations (['/home/jpf911/COVID19-Vaccination-Tracker/COVID19-Vaccination-Tracker/vaccination_tracker/tracker', './tracker']); you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute.
2021-04-23 16:20:38,676:   File "/var/www/jpf911_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
2021-04-23 16:20:38,677:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-04-23 16:20:38,677: 
2021-04-23 16:20:38,677:   File "/home/jpf911/.virtualenvs/vaccinationvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-04-23 16:20:38,677:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-04-23 16:20:38,678: 
2021-04-23 16:20:38,678:   File "/home/jpf911/.virtualenvs/vaccinationvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2021-04-23 16:20:38,678:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679: 
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679:   File "/home/jpf911/.virtualenvs/vaccinationvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679: 
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679:   File "/home/jpf911/.virtualenvs/vaccinationvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 255, in create
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679:     return app_config_class(app_name, app_module)
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679: 
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679:   File "/home/jpf911/.virtualenvs/vaccinationvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 49, in __init__
2021-04-23 16:20:38,679:     self.path = self._path_from_module(app_module)
2021-04-23 16:20:38,680: 
2021-04-23 16:20:38,680:   File "/home/jpf911/.virtualenvs/vaccinationvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 88, in _path_from_module
2021-04-23 16:20:38,680:     raise ImproperlyConfigured(
```

> Here are my Configurations:

Code: [Source Code & Working Directory.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVFnq.png)

Wsgi Configurations: [Wsgi config.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83j6V.png)

Virtual Environmet: [Virtual env.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRtVz.png)

Static Files & Security: [Static_Files & Security.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy4yy.png)

Settings.py: [Settings 1.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONEND.png) [Settings 2.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDqB6.png)

Console: [Console.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VW9B.png)

Comment: Try setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['https://jpf911.pythonanywhere.com', 'jpf911.pythonanywhere.com', http://jpf911.pythonanywhere.com/']`

Comment: Error still the same

Comment: Hello @jpf911 this happens sometimes because of  deleting of `__init__.py` check here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222093/14457833

Answer (score 0):

You have a module (in this case tracker) that appears in you python path in 2 different places. You can either change your python path so that the module only occurs in one location (in your case, you can either remove . from the python path, or /home/jpf911/COVID19-Vaccination-Tracker/COVID19-Vaccination-Tracker/vaccination_tracker/). Or you can add an AppConfig object to your project that tells Django which of those paths to use (search the Django docs for AppConfig for details)