# IIS server django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, iis

I am trying to deploy my django project on windows IIS server using wfastcgi. This project contains multiple apps and post completion of all the steps mentioned when i try to open the url it gives me following error.

Thanks in Advance!!

> File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
> env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
> File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
> handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
> File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 605, in get_wsgi_handler
> handler = handler()
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
> django.setup(set_prefix=False)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django_*init*_.py", line 24, in setup
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
> app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 222, in create
> return app_config_class(app_name, app_module)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 47, in **init**
> self.path = self._path_from_module(app_module)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 86, in _path_from_module
> raise ImproperlyConfigured(
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The app module <module 'OnboardingApp' (namespace)> has multiple filesystem locations (['D:\RPA\CoreRPA_Webapp\OnboardingApp', 'D:\RPA\CoreRPA_Webapp\.\OnboardingApp']); you must configure this app with an AppConfig subclass with a 'path' class attribute.

Comment: If possible, please provide specific steps to reproduce the issue, which may help narrow down the issue. Have you looked at the answers to similar cases, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205264/django-app-improperly-configured-the-app-module-has-multiple-filesystem-locati

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me like a charm
Thanks to @Otuoma Sanya
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68536324/20721005

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
import os
from django.conf import settings

class TranslatorConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'AppName'
    path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'AppName')
```